# Compound literals in MSVC

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, gcc, compound-literals

In GCC, I'm able to do this:

```
(CachedPath){ino}
inode->data = (struct Data)DATA_INIT;
```

where:

```
struct CachedPath
{
    Ino ino;
};

typedef int8_t Depth;
struct Data
{
    Offset size;
    Blkno root;
    Depth depth;
};
#define DATA_INIT {0, -1, 0}
```

MSVC gives the following error for these kind of casts:

```
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

**How can I do this in MSVC?** Further note that the code has been converted from C99, where I used designated initializers for this, and then cast it similarly. Any clarity on how these various features relate between C99, and MSVC/GCC implementations of C++ is appreciated.

Comment: You might consider changing the title. Compound literals are not a cast operator. The set of types which are valid in a cast and the set which are valid for compound literals are completely disjoint, and the C standard makes a point of this.

Comment: This "duplicate" predates the alternative by FIVE YEARS. Also the duplicate is GCC and clang specific, this is for MSVC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The construct `(Type){initialisers}` is not a cast operation, but it is the syntactic construct of a *compound literal*.
This is a C99 construct, which GCC also supports in its C++ compiler as an extension. As far as I can determine, compound literals are not supported up to and including MSVC 2012, in either its C or C++ mode. The support in C mode was introduced later, in MSVC 2013. In C++ mode it is still not supported and I believe it is unlikely support will be added.

For MSVC 2012 and older, the alternatives for this construct are

- Explicitly declare and initialise a temporary object of the desired struct type and use that instead of the compound literal in the assignment
- Instead of doing a single assignment with the compound literal, use a separate assignment for each individual member.

Answer (score 3):

MSVC is not conformant to C99 and only loosely conformant to previous versions of the C standard. I know no way to do what you want *syntactically* with MSVC, but the same effect can be obtained by using `static const` structs instead of anonymous compound literal constants, and local `struct` variables that are initialized with the correct values instead of anonymous compound literals that are nonconstant.

The idea behind this approach is that a C99 compound literal is (at least nearly) equivalent to a local variable of the same type at the same scope, initialized with the contents of the braces. Using `static const` structs in the case where the data is constant is just an optimization (it will likely produce smaller/faster code than the C99 compound literal approach).

Comment: MSVC is very precisely conformant to C89/90 standard. What is the strange claim of being "loosely conformant" based upon?

Comment: Most of the conformance problems I know about are the standard library and related to internationalization amendments ("C95" I think it's typically called). For instance, incorrect behavior of the `%s` and `%ls` format specifiers in `wprintf` and `printf`, respectively, and the use of multi-`wchar_t` characters (UTF-16) in ways that breaks the C multibyte/wide conversion API. I suspect the compiler/compilation environment itself has some bugs too though - like keyword/function/type names that conflict with those reserved for the application.

Comment: What do you mean by "use static const structs"?

Comment: Along with `#define DATA_INIT {0, -1, 0}`, use `static const struct Data data_init = DATA_INIT;`, and then use the latter for assignments and the former for initializations.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio, since VS2013, supports Compound literals and Designated initializers.
[Which C99 features are available in the MS Visual Studio compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9610747)

Example:

```
// main.c
#include <stdio.h>

void func(int(*array)[3]);

int main()
{
    // Designated initializers

    int a[6] = { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 }; // [0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0]

    struct point { int x, y; };
    struct point p = { .y = 13, .x = 27 }; // x = 27, y = 13

    union foo { int i; double d; };
    union foo f = { .d = 4 }; // d = 4.0

    struct point ptarray[5] = { [2].y = 34, [2].x = 42, [0].x = 58 };
    // (58 0), (0 0), (42 34), (0 0), (0 0)

    // Compound literals

    int *a1 = NULL;
    a1 = (int[6]) { [4] = 29, [2] = 15 }; // [0, 0, 15, 0, 29, 0]

    struct point p1;
    p1 = (struct point) { .y = 13, .x = 27 }; // x = 27, y = 13

    union foo f1;
    f1 = (union foo) { .d = 4 }; // d = 4.0

    struct point *ptarray1 = NULL;
    ptarray1 = (struct point[5]) { [2].y = 34, [2].x = 42, [0].x = 58 };
    // (58 0), (0 0), (42 34), (0 0), (0 0)

    int *p2 = NULL;
    p2 = (int[2]) { -1 };
    p2 = (int[]) { -73, 89, 92 };
    func(&(int[]) { -73, 89, 92 });

    return 0;
}

void func(int(*array)[3])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (*array)[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MSVC is a mix of standards, and is not fully compliant with most of them, thus, you'll probably need to use a default initializer/constructor, like so (C++ way):

```
#define DATA_INIT 0,-1,0
inode->data = Data(DATA_INIT);

struct Data
{
    Offset size;
    Blkno root;
    Depth depth;

    Data(Offset size, Blkno root, Depth depth) : size(size), root(root), depth(depth)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: @R.. please read the tags and the OP's post, this is C++ code, like the OP requested

Comment: You've forgot to define a constructor accepting 3 parameters for `struct Data`.

Comment: @atzz: good catch, I'll add that, though I remember that MSVC could auto initialize without one, can't test that at the moment though

Comment: Yes, this would be great if C++ created a default constructor accepting all the members of the struct in order.