# Accessing member of compound literal using Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, struct

Excuse me for the title of this question, I will probably update the title once I have my answer.

I have this ancient code compiling and working with gcc 4.x:

```
struct S {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main(void)
{
    return (struct S){1,2}.a;
}
```

As you can see I cast the `{1,2}` to `struct S` to access the member `a`. How is this feature called in the C language? Or what are the correct terms to apply for this construct?

Is this feature supported in any of the visual studio versions?

Comment: It is like GCC [6.25 Compound Literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html)

Comment: I found this question, please help me close mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869963/compound-literals-in-msvc

Comment: @Patrick B: My copy of MSVS 2012 Premium does *not* support it.  I get `error C2059: syntax error: '{'`.  I understand C99 *will* be supported in MSVS2013.  You can download it for free and try it: [MSVS 2013 Express Preview](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39313).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called [**compound literal**](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html), which is introduced in C99. The relevant part in the standard is [6.5.2.5 Compound literals](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.2.5)

The bad news is Visual Studio only supports C89 right now, so this feature is not supported in Visual Studio.

Comment: VS 2013 introduced support for C99 compound literals in C mode.