# why type casting on non-pointer struct give syntax error

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, ffmpeg

I am using Visual C++ express 2008 try to compile code similar to below:

no problem

```
{
  ...
  AVRational test = {1, 1000};
  ...
}
```

but **has problem** when it is as below:

```
{
  ...
  AVRational test = (AVRational){1, 1000};
  ...
}
```

gave errors:

```
1>..\..\..\projects\test\xyz.cpp(1139) : error C2059: syntax error : '{'
1>..\..\..\projects\test\xyz.cpp(1139) : error C2143: syntax error : missing   ';' before '{'
1>..\..\..\projects\test\xyz.cpp(1139) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
```

where AVRational (ffmpeg.org library) is defined as:

```
typedef struct AVRational{
    int num; ///< numerator
    int den; ///< denominator
} AVRational;
```

FFmpeg come with some pre-define value such as

```
#define AV_TIME_BASE_Q (AVRational){1, AV_TIME_BASE}
```

which is used as below

```
av_rescale_q(seek_target, AV_TIME_BASE_Q, pFormatCtx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);
```

will failed to compile on Visual C++ express 2008

It seem like the same code will be compiled with no error/warning on gcc compiler. Why I get this error on VC++? Is it a C/C++ standard way to do casting on struct value? Anyway I can avoid this error while still able to use the defined AV_TIME_BASE_Q?

Comment: try surrounding your { } with ( ) ... I've seen that work in other contexts.

Comment: do you mean do something like this "av_rescale_q(seek_target, (AV_TIME_BASE_Q), pFormatCtx->streams[stream_index]->time_base);"? Not working too. Similar errors appear.

Comment: `AVRational test = (AVRational){1, 1000};` is not valid C++. It's a C99 feature called "compound literals", and gcc supports it as an extension.

Comment: After a quick review of the ffmpeg.org site, which says it is platform independent, what FFmpeg version is being used?

Comment: So, i think the problem is because VC++ 2008 does not support C99. Seem like VC++ 2013 does support that. Also I actually able to pass in a local AVRational test variable into av_rescale_q. It just that I can't use the predefined AV_TIME_BASE_Q. I must redefined it myself without the "compound literals".

Comment: I think should not be too old as I downloaded from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/ which provided the static dev ffmpeg library for Windows. I think it is 2.0.1.

Comment: Just tested. VC++ express 2013 does NOT allow the "compound literals" too.

Comment: For possible fixes, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869963/compound-literals-in-msvc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VC++ 2013 does not allow compound literals in C++ but it allows them in C.  Options:

1. Rename your program with a .c suffix
2. Switch on the /TC flag for the program that does not compile.

The other alternative if you wish to keep to C++ is to change the declaration of AV_TIME_BASE_Q in the header file

```
static const AVRational AV_TIME_BASE_Q = {1, AV_TIME_BASE};
```

Then it will be using the constant instead of the compound literal.

Comment: You are right. By right clicking the project -> properties -> configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> compile as -> use the /TC option instead of default option, then the code will be compiled successfully. Did on VC++ express 2013. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Use `av_get_time_base_q()` instead of `AV_TIME_BASE_Q` for C++ or VS. 
[This was fixed in a patch](http://libav-devel.libav.narkive.com/ZQCWfTun/patch-0-2-fix-avutil-h-usage-from-c)

Answer (score 0):

For  compound-literals errors in C++

wrong:

```
 this->buffer.enqueue((tone_t) { duration, frequency });
```

correct:

```
tone_t tone = { duration, frequency };
this->buffer.enqueue(tone);
```