# Are compound literals Standard C++?

Tags: c++, c++14, compound-literals

[Compound Literals](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-compound-literals/184401404) are a C99 construct. Even though I can do this in C++ :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    for (auto i : (float[2]) {2.7, 3.1}) cout << i << endl;
}
```

It seems that for example MSVC supports it [as an extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3870137/4224575). Yet all compilers I can get my hands on, compile the above mentioned code.

So **is this a feature available in C++14** ? Is there a different standard term (It looks to me like just creating a temporary using braced initialization) ?

---

**Side Note** : "Compound Literals" (or whatever I should call the above) are a [pack expansion context](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25683817/4224575) ( just to mention a functionality )

Comment: Ugh, use a `std::array<float, 2>` and you know it's safe, why bother?

Comment: `for (auto i : {2.7, 3.1}) cout << i << endl;` works just fine and is standard.

Comment: @T.C. Real literals are of type double so it isn't the same.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is an extension that both [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Compound-Literals.html) and `clang` support. The gcc document says:

> As an extension, GCC supports compound literals in C90 mode and in C++, though the semantics are somewhat different in C++.

if you build with [-pedantic](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Standards.html) you should receive a warning, for example `clang` says (*[see it live](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/iISmBUMSUFeI4LbL)*):

> warning: compound literals are a C99-specific feature [-Wc99-extensions]

Note, the semantic differences in C++ are not minor and code that would be well-defined in C99 can have undefined behavior in C++ with this extension:

> In C++, a compound literal designates a temporary object, which only
>   lives until the end of its full-expression. As a result, well-defined
>   C code that takes the address of a subobject of a compound literal can
>   be undefined in C++.

Answer (score 32):

```
(float[2]) {2.7, 3.1}
```

is a C99 compound literal. Some compilers support it in C++ as an extension.

```
float[2] {2.7, 3.1}
```

is a syntax error.

Given `using arr = float[2];`,

```
arr {2.7, 3.1}
```

is valid C++ that list-initializes a temporary array of two `float`s.

```
{2.7, 3.1}
```

is called a *braced-init-list*.

Finally, for your code,

```
for (auto i : {2.7, 3.1}) cout << i << endl;
```

works equally well and is perfectly valid C++ - this constructs a `std::initializer_list<double>` under the hood. If you really want `float`s, add the `f` suffix to the numbers.