# What does the standard C++03 say about type (cast) conversion of agregate initializer?

Tags: c++, types, type-conversion, c++03

I want to pass agregate initializer as function argument. But c++03 doesnt allow to do this.

What does the standard C++03 say about type conversion of agregate initializer? Is it correct?

```
struct A
{
    int a, b;
};

void f(const A&){}

int main()
{
    f({1, 2}); // c++03 doesnt allow this
    f((A){1, 2}); // but c-style cast allows
                  //convert agregate initializer
}
```

Comment: That is actually a compound literal see this recent [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28116467/1708801)