# Is there any syntax to hardcode vector as parameter?

Tags: c++, syntax

for example, I can hardcode array as parameter like that:

```
void test(pair<string,int> v[],int size){
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        printf("%s %d\n",v[i].first.c_str(),v[i].second);
    }
}

int main(){
    test((pair<string,int>[]){make_pair("a",1),make_pair("b",2)},2);
    return 0;
}
```

so that I don't need to create a temp variable of pair v[] and then no need to worry about the variable name of the temp variable, is there any similar syntax if using vector:

```
void test(vector<pair<string,int> > v){
    for(pair<string,int> p : v){
        printf("%s %d\n",p.first.c_str(),p.second);
    }
}
```

?

Comment: You can use `std::initializer_list` to initialize a `std::vector `.

Comment: In C++11, simply `test({{"a", 1}, {"b", 2}})`.

Comment: Your parameter is a pointer, not an array.

Comment: Also, compound literals are not a thing in C++, so your code is invalid. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116467/are-compound-literals-standard-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because C++11 introduced [list initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) with the help of [`std::initializer_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (not to be confused with [constructor initializer lists](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)), you can indeed use a `std::vector` (which has been modified to have a [constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) accepting `std::initializer_list`) and you can simply do

```
test({{"a",1), {"b",2}});
```