# How to get float address for use with memcpy?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory-address, memcpy

I'm trying to fill byte/char array with memory address of float variable (array length is 4 bytes = pointer), but whatever I do it keeps getting float value instead of address:

```
float f = 20.0f;

memcpy(data, &f, sizeof(data));
```

Debugging it with:

```
printf("Array: %#X, %#X, %#X, %#X", data[0], data[1], data[2], data[3]);
```

...gives float value (20.0) in hex format:

```
Array: 0, 0, 0XA0, 0X41
```

What I need is memory address of float. I tried casting/dereferencing it in some different ways, but can't get it to work...

Comment: Question with interest, why is it needed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's how `memcpy` works: it takes a pointer to *data* it will copy. Your *data* is pointer to float, so you need to pass pointer to pointer to float:

```
#include <cstring>

int main() {
   float f = 20.0f;
   float* pf = &f;
   char data[sizeof(pf)];
   memcpy(data, &pf, sizeof(data));
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should also mention that on a 64 bit machine (common, nowadays) a pointer should take 8 chars/byte.

Comment: @Bob__: sure, thanks! Zax Ftw: read above, and in general, better describe what you're doing in separate question and ask if it's a good thing to do

Comment: But this is for 32 bit, so pointer is 4 bytes, I didn't want to post more details because its completely unrelated and niche stuff.

Answer (score 0):

For a C solution, save the hex data to a *compound literal*.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char data[sizeof (float*)];
  printf("%p\n", (void*) data);
  float f;
  printf("%p\n", (void*) &f);

  memcpy(data, &(float *){&f}, sizeof (float*));
  for (unsigned i = 0; i<sizeof data; i++) {
    printf("%02hhX ", data[i]);
  }
  puts("");
}
```

Output

```
0xffffcba8
0xffffcba4
A4 CB FF FF 00 00 00 00
```

The address is valid until the end of the block.
Adjust endian/print order as desired.

Comment: Curious why this compound literaI doesn't compile in C++. I really like this one line solution, but getting too many brackets errors.

Comment: @ZaxFtw IIRC, C++ does not support _compound literal_.  See [Are compound literals Standard C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28116467/2410359)