# Convert a literal to an lvalue

Tags: c++, types

In C, there is the concept of a [compound literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal) which can be used to take any literal and make it addressable. For instance:

```
int* p = &(int){0};
```

Compound literals do not exist in C++. Is there another construct in C++ that can turn a literal into an lvalue? For example:

```
// Something semantically equivalent to this, but without the need of a declaration
int n = 0;
int* p = &n;
```

---

EDIT:

Having a function or type to create the solution is fine, as long as no more than a single inline statement is needed to facilitate its use. For example, `int* p = new int(0);` requires two lines per instance of use: one line where it is used, and one line at the end of scope to delete the allocation.

Solution must be doable in standard C++; no extensions.

Comment: Is there any good reason why you want to do this?

Comment: There are instances when using OpenGL where I want to pass many literals by pointer. I could make declarations, but an inline value I can use and forget about would be less bloat.

Comment: Well an extra layer of indirection may not hurt. You can write wrappers for that; But see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28116467/are-compound-literals-standard-c) if you want to use non-standard extensions

Comment: `int* a = new int(3);` Something like this?

Comment: @artur99 This adds to my problem, since I would still need two lines (statement + a delete at the end of scope), but now have to make sure I'm not leaking memory.

Comment: @WhiZTiM Good to know, but unfortunately my environment prohibits extensions. The solution needs to be standard C++.

Comment: *"using OpenGL where I want to pass many literals by pointer"* could you provide some example code? This sounds like you фку scattering magic numbers around.

Comment: @VTT I will have to get back to you with the code snippet. Regardless of where it is deemed a good use case or not, the question asks if there is some equivalent to compound literals in C++.

Comment: Do you need the lifetime of the object to extend for more than one statement, or is it just passing a pointer to a (C-style) function that will use it only during the call (like typical `const&` parameters)?

Comment: @Davis Herring Your c style assumption is correct. It only needs to exist for the call like a const& parameter.

Comment: Instead of `int*` you can use `unique_ptr<int>` and it will magically delete itself at the end of the scope.

Comment: @BoPersson This meets my criteria, but would cause an unnecessary heap allocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define

```
template<class T>
T& lvalue_cast(T &&t) {return t;}
```

which accepts literals (among other things). The temporary [lasts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime) until the end of the complete expression lexically containing its creation (presumably [materialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Temporary_materialization) to bind the reference for `lvalue_cast`).  Obviously restricting its use to that interval is up to you.

Comment: It's probably worth expanding on the lifetime effects. In C, a compound literal inside a function dies when the enclosing block ends; I believe this would die much sooner.

Comment: @user2357112: Sure—I checked on the needed lifetime in a comment, but I mentioned it here now too.