# Hi, I have trouble using pointers

Tags: c

This C code works fine in Codeblocks but not in other environments. I think Codeblocks automatically uses pointer and modifies the code

return (Result){sum, mean, var}; << This part has an error in visual studio.
error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax

Would there be any suggestion that can fix the code to use pointers? Thank you for reading my question!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SIZE 6
typedef struct Result {
   float sum, mean, variance;
}Result;

Result Statistics(int a[]);

int main()
{
   int array[SIZE] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6 };
   Result result;
   result = Statistics(array);
   printf("Sum=%.2f\n", result.sum);
   printf("Mean=%.2f\n", result.mean);
   printf("Variance=%.2f\n", result.variance);
   return 0;
}


Result Statistics(int a[])
{

   float sum, mean, var, sum2, diff;
   int i;
   for (sum = 0, i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      sum += (float)a[i];

   }
   mean = sum / SIZE;
   for (sum2 = 0, i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
      diff = (float)a[i] - mean;
      sum2 += diff * diff;
   }
   var = sum2 / SIZE;
   return (Result){sum, mean, var};
}
```

Comment: Compound literals were introduced in C99, your code seems correct, what is the exact error? _I think Codeblocks automatically uses pointer and modifies the code_. Codeblocks is an IDE not a compiler, and no, the compiler doesn't return any pointer, it returns a `Result` or it doesn't compile (depending on your version).

Comment: Thanks for responding. The error i'm getting is
error C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax
on visual studio.

Comment: I would have bet 1000 dollars :)

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't support the C language well. As for Codeblocks/mingw/gcc, they shipped it with a fairly old version of gcc for quite some time. Any version before 5.0 defaults to C90, even though they supported standard C too.

Comment: Check this: [Compound literals in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3869963/1606345)

Comment: When answering requests for more information, edit the question to provide the information. Answering in comments in insufficient.

Comment: Thank you, everyone for responding so kindly. Helped me a lot!

Comment: I didn't find any pointer related error, there is no use of pointers in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your compiler does not support standard C. Change

```
return (Result){sum, mean, var};
```

to:

```
{
    Result temp = {sum, mean, var};
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Pedantically, it should be `{ Result ... return tmp; }` since C90 doesn't allow declarations in the middle of the block.

Comment: @Lundin: OP’s Visual Studio is not C90 either. But added nonetheless.

Comment: Come to think of it, it may not be C at all, they could have compiled as C++.